# Finding $\sin(x/2)$ given a $\tan$ using half-angle identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I find $\sin(x/2)$ given $\tan(x) = -5.099$ and $x$ is in Quadrant IV, assuming that $0 < x < 2\pi$?

I know I have to use half-angle identities in some way, but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first goal is to find $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. You know the following things:

- $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.
- $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = -5.099$.
- Because $x$ is in Quadrant IV, $\cos x > 0$ and $\sin x < 0$.

We will only need $\cos x$ for now, but finding $\sin x$ and finding $\cos x$ goes hand in hand.

Once you know that, you want to solve for $$\sin \frac x2 = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos x}{2}}.$$
The sign of $\sin \frac x2$, once again, cannot be determined from the value of $\cos x$. You have to ask yourself: if $x$ is in Quadrant IV, what is the range of possible values of $x$ (as an angle)? What, then, is the range of possible values of $\frac x2$? Is $\sin x$ positive or negative for those values?

Comment: Thank you so much! There were a few identities I wasn't aware of that I didn't have, you gave me a push in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Using the double angle formula for $\cos$
$$\cos^2 (x)=1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
$$\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$